# After Auto-ARC Conversion: Assigning retained object to unsafe property; object will be released after assignment

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I just converted an old project to ARC using Xcode's automatic refactoring.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *cards;
```

was replaced by:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *cards;
```

This makes sense because what I've read is that "strong" is the default state. However, the following line is giving me the error in the title:

```
self.cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:54];
```

The error is solved by adding `strong` back in where retain used to be:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *cards;
```

However... if I need to go back and put `strong` in to every @property declaration that was `retain`... why did the ARC refactoring remove them all?

Comment: Actually, the default memory management semantic is `assign`, not `strong`, which is why you're getting the warning message.

Comment: jlehr isn't right about the default memory management semantic. but he's not wrong either. before LLVM 3.1 & ARC the default indeed has been assign. but nowadays it's strong. this unfortunately is very poorly documented. see nschum's answer.

Comment: Now that the default is strong, the warning should have gone away. Why it hasn't?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I've run into the same warning and opened an Technical Support Incident. The engineer verified that **the default was changed from "assign" to "strong"** for reasons of consistency within ARC.

He said both the warning and the documentation are wrong and will be fixed. Until that is done, I would **avoid the implicit default** altogether!

Explicitly adding "strong" (as BJ Homer suggested) is a safe way to silence the warning and be compatible. But don't assume properties to be unretained by default. Always put "weak" or "assign" there, too.

Edit: The [clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property) now officially documents this change. The warning has been [fixed](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=rev&revision=148355).

Edit 2: Xcode 4.4 apparently includes the fix.

Comment: So the warning has been fixed. When will we see this fix in xcode?

Comment: @nschum this warning still happens in latest version of Xcode 4.3.3. why?

Comment: Unfortunately, the linked commit was to LLVM's *trunk*. So I wouldn't necessarily expect the fix to show up in a maintenance release. I haven't tried Xcode 4.4.

Comment: what is LLVM's trunk? This warning is annoying. Can we turn that off for a while.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with XCode 4.4.1.

Answer (score 8):

It looks wrong that it converted `nonatomic, retain` to `nonatomic`. I've always seen it convert to `nonatomic, strong`. If you can produce a simple project that converts in the way you saw it then I suggest [filing a radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/) with it.

I assume by the way that you're using the latest Xcode.

Comment: I am using 4.3.1 which I downloaded from the App Store yesterday, so it better be the newest. :)

Comment: Yes, this is, unfortunately, a known bug in 4.3.1. I reported it myself the other day. The easiest workaround is simply to do a project regex replace of `retain(,|\))` with `strong\1`. Then run the ARC conversion again.

Comment: Definitely file a radar then @KennyWyland

Comment: can we just suppress the warning for a while till xcode produce a fix.