# Creating UI in code with properties

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, properties

When I create UI via Interface Builder and then attach to IBOutlets I always set the property to weak...

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *someLabel;
```

Then in the code for the `UIViewController` I can refer to `self.someLabel` or `_someLabel` and it works fine.

However, if I set up the UI in code...

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UILabel *someLabel;
```

and...

```
self.someLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,10,10)];
```

Then I get the warning...

```
Assigning retained object to weak property; object will be released after assignment.
```

My usual fix for this is to just change the property to `strong` but I'm not sure if this is correct?

Is that OK? If not, is there another way to fix this?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752525/after-auto-arc-conversion-assigning-retained-object-to-unsafe-property-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My usual fix for this is to just change the property to strong but I'm not sure if this is correct?

This is 100% correct. The reason IB-based properties are declared `weak` is that the view created from the NIB object already retains the corresponding UI element, so you do not need a `strong` reference from your code.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I thought this was the case I just wanted someone else to confirm what I was doing was correct as I hadn't read or heard it anywhere. Thanks